# Can I get the standard currency format to use a negative sign instead of parentheses?

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are many places in my project where I try to display currency with the built-in `{0:C}` currency format.  If the number is negative, it surrounds the value in parentheses.  I want it to use a negative sign instead.

My web.config has culture set to `auto`, and it resolves to `en-US`.

The ideal solution would be some global web.config or other setting that would make the `{0:C}` display the negative sign for the `en-US` culture, but I'm open to other, less awesome solutions as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Globally changing format of negative currency numbers in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994601/globally-changing-format-of-negative-currency-numbers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think a combination of the answers here will get you closer to what you want.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName == ci.DisplayName)
    {
        ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        ci.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    }
}
```

If you want to not have any code that deals with a single culture like this... I believe you need to build your own culture... [Check this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167331/how-to-change-default-culture-settings-in-a-net-web-application)

Answer (score 26):

You have to specify the correct [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) which is probably 1.

```
Decimal dec = new Decimal(-1234.4321);
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1; 
String str = String.Format(culture, "{0:C}", dec);
Console.Write(str);
```

demo: http://ideone.com/HxSqT

output:

```
-$1,234.43
```

Comment: I think the CurrencyNegativePattern is supposed to be 1. In the US the currency symbol should be on the left side not the right side.

Comment: @Sam: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It is definitely easy to change 5 to 1. :)

Comment: @Sam: Yes of course. It's up to OP to chose whatever he want since he hasn't provided the exact desired format. But it's easy with this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the following advantages over the other answers:

- Clones the system's other existing `CurrentCulture` settings instead of resetting them to `en-US` defaults.
- Only modifies `CurrentCulture` which deals with currency, not `CurrentUICulture` where the system may have a different text language set.
- Only modifies `CurrencyNegativePattern` if the system does not specify a custom setting for it.
- Minimizes extra calls.

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name.Equals("en-US", StringComparison.Ordinal)
    && Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern == 0)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
}
```

### Alternate solution

If you want to change the `CurrencyNegativePattern` but don't want to check if the system is set to `en-US` or if the system has an existing custom `CurrencyNegativePattern` setting, but keeping the other advantages of the first solution:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your question.

You want to show the currency format depending on a culture.

Everytime you do culture specific things, .NET looks at `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

You can set the culture you want in ASP.NET in the global.asax `BeginRequest` method.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"); // put the culture you want in here

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me and I hope it helps others

var strTotAm = dr["TotalCost"].ToString().Trim();

```
                                var TotalAm = Regex.Replace(strTotAm, @"[^\d\.\-\(]", "").Replace("(", "-");

                                dVehTotalAm = (decimal.Parse(TotalAm,
                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowParentheses |
                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite |
                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |
                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint |
                                            System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign));
```