# .net 6 converts negative decimal number to currency different from .net48

Tags: c#, .net, string, format, .net-6.0

I have a method that converts decimal to string currency

```
public static string ToCurrencyWithParentheses(this decimal initDecimal)
{
    return initDecimal.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

We recently switched from .net48 to .net6 in a project and I noticed that the method began to work differently. On .net48 I would pass a negative number `-58.45` into the method and get `($58.45)`, but now on .net6 I get `-$58.45`.
Can anyone tell me how to fix the method without badcodding so that it processes the number correctly? Or is this a bug?

I couldn't google ready-made solutions. I tried using string.Format() instead of ToString() and stuff like that, but nothing works.

Comment: Passing a negative number and getting a positive result seems like a bug. I'd think that the .NET 6 behaviour is correct, no?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - it's not a positive result.  Using parenthesis to represent a negative number is a bookkeeping convention in the US, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number: *In bookkeeping, amounts owed are often represented by red numbers, or a number in parentheses, as an alternative notation to represent negative numbers.* and https://nstarfinance.com/what-does-parentheses-mean-in-accounting/: *In accounting, you might see parentheses around a number to show that it’s negative.* (I once got **very** confused by some 20th century IRS tax forms that followed that convention.)

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama if you go to Number.Formatting.cs from System package you will notice that Format "C" should transform numbers like -12345.6789 to ($12,345.68). This is correct behavior

Comment: I've made the output a little clearer in your question, since it wasn't clear to me that the parenthesis weren't added by you.

Comment: It seems related to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks), but I don't know if you can get .NET 6 to behave the same without a custom culture (example of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696209/3181933)). Amusingly, I tried using negative pattern 0, and it didn't include the currency symbol without also specifying that via `CurrencySymbol`.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama that works for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Since .Net5, ICU became the default globalization library, add these lines to your project file to have old formats:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

See [Use NLS instead of ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#use-nls-instead-of-icu)

Comment: Ah, that's the root of the problem. Thank you!