# Formatting and parsing decimals with the Arabic (Saudi Arabia) culture

Tags: c#, formatting, numbers, arabic, cultureinfo

Consider the following C# code:

```cs
decimal value = -123.456m;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-SA");

string formatted = value.ToString("e", culture);
Console.WriteLine(formatted);

decimal parsed = decimal.Parse(formatted, culture);
Console.WriteLine(parsed);
```

Allowing for the fact that `decimal.Parse` doesn't even work in this instance, this code produces some unusual results:

- `-1,234560e +002` is what I **see** printed in the console.
- `؜-1٫234560e؜+002` is what I get if I copy the text in the console.
- `002+1,23456e-` is what `formatted` displays in the debugger.
- `\u061c-1٫234560e\u061c+002` is what I get if I copy the value from the debugger to a new string.

**Questions**

1. Why does formatting with `ar-SA` produce this unusual result?
2. Why can this not be parsed when providing the exact same culture?

If there is any culture-specific documentation in the .NET docs regarding this sort of formatting, I'd greatly appreciate the links so I can read further into this.

**Update**

As per this comment from [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc):

> **Finally, do you get the same issue with double instead of decimal?** If double round-trips while decimal does not, that argues for this being a .NET bug with ICU for formatting of decimals using scientific notation. (Incidentally, formatting of decimals using scientific notation looks sort of like an edge case to me. Usually decimals are formatted using standard notation.)

```cs
double value = -123.456;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-SA");

string formatted = value.ToString("e", culture);
Console.WriteLine(formatted);

double parsed = double.Parse(formatted, culture);
Console.WriteLine(parsed);
```

This also produces some unusual results, although in this instance `double.Parse` works:

- `-1,234560e +002` is what I **see** printed in the console.
- `؜-1٫234560e؜+002` is what I get if I copy the text in the console.
- `002+1,234560e-` is what formatted displays in the debugger.
- `\u061c-1٫234560e\u061c+002` is what I get if I copy the value from the debugger to a new string.

Therefore it appears that `double.ToString("e", culture)` formats the number the same way.

**Note:** I am using NET 8.0, Rider and MacOS. CurrentCulture is en-GB.

Comment: I suspect you are encountering bugs or inconsistencies in right-to-left text rendering.  From [Arabic & Persian Layout Requirements](https://www.w3.org/TR/alreq/#h_direction): *Arabic script is written from right to left. Numbers, even Arabic numbers, are written from left to right, as is text in a script that is normally left-to-right.*

Comment: Incidentally what version of .NET/.NET Core are you using?

Comment: @dbc .NET 8.0, Rider and MacOS. CurrentCulture is en-GB

Comment: This is clearly something to do with right-to-left text formatting & rendering in Arabic.  [U+061C](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/061C) is the ARABIC LETTER MARK.  It is an [implicit directional mark](https://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Implicit_Directional_Marks) that is *used to change the way adjacent characters are grouped with respect to text direction*.  However, I don't know why `value.ToString("e", culture);` might be adding it so I can't provide a proper answer to your question.

Comment: Also note that, starting in .NET 5, MSFT switched their default globalization library to ICU  from NLS, see [.net 6 converts negative decimal number to currency different from .net48](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77191989/3744182) and [.NET globalization and ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu).  Possibly switching back to NLS could help, see [Use NLS instead of ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#use-nls-instead-of-icu).

Comment: Finally, do you get the same issue with `double` instead of `decimal`?  If `double` round-trips while `decimal` does not, that argues for this being a .NET bug with ICU for formatting of decimals using scientific notation.  (Incidentally, formatting of decimals using scientific notation looks sort of like an edge case to me.  Usually decimals are formatted using standard notation.)

Comment: *MacOS* -- Hmm, I am not sure that NLS is even available on MacOS.  So you may be stuck with ICU.  That being said, see [App-local ICU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#app-local-icu): *Each release of ICU may bring with it bug fixes as well as updated Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) data that describes the world's languages... .NET 5 and later versions enable apps on both Windows and Unix to carry and use their own copy of ICU.* and then...

Comment: [macOS behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#macos-behavior): *macOS has a different behavior for resolving dependent dynamic libraries from the load commands specified in the `Mach-O` file than the Linux loader.*  You may want to make sure exactly what version of ICU you are using, and whether you are using the one built into .NET 8 or not.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your comments, that's really helpful. I've updated the question to include a test using `double` as well.

Comment: OK, seems like you need to use a special format for parsing `decimal` using scientific notation.  See [Parse a Number from Exponential Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879503).