# CurrentUICulture determining wrong culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, currentculture

**TL;DR:** .NET 6 is refusing to render MVC pages when the browser's language is set to `zh-TW`.
 
When my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application renders a page, if the user has the browser language set to `Chinese (Traditional)` (`zh-TW`), it displays `Chinese (Simplified)` (`zh-CN`) and the CurrentCulture name is shown as `zh`.
 
I have the following language resource files:

- strings.zh-CHS.resx
- strings.zh-CHT.resx
- Strings.zh-cn.resx
- strings.zh-Hans.resx
- strings.zh-Hant.resx
- Strings.zh-TW.resx
- strings.zh.resx
   
  (I have checked that the correct translations are in those files.)
   
  In order to define which resource files should be used when performing language selection, my `Configure` method contains this code:

```
CultureInfo[] allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var supportedCultures = allCultures.Where(c => (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(location, c.Name)) || c.Name.StartsWith("zh-")) && c.LCID != 127).ToList();
 
// ***added here***
 
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

When debugging, the `supportedCultures` list includes the `CultureInfo` objects with these names:

- zh
- zh-Hans
- zh-Hant
- zh-Hant-TW
   
  In an effort to avoid the selection defaulting to the first matching language in the list, I have added this code to the `***added here***` line above:

```
supportedCultures.Reverse();
```

How do I get .net to recognise that the browser is requesting the `zh-TW` culture?

Comment: In the past, you could simply set Thread.CurrentCulture to the culture obtained from the client in early stages of the request?

Comment: What does the `Request.UserLanguages` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another ICU issue, as `zh-TW` is [not an ISO standard name](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12263#issuecomment-473994613), `AllCultures` will not contain it, and `zh-TW` will not match `zh-Hant-TW`.

I can find 2 solutions:

1. Manually add `zh-TW`

   ```
   supportedCultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-TW"));
   ```
2. Use NLS instead of ICU, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77192077/6196568